# In the Eclipse HTML editor, is there an easy way to have custom tags available in content assist (autocomplete)?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I'm learning to use a new hosted e-commerce system at work which uses a proprietary markup/scripting language for its page templates. They are similar to JSP pages (although the server tags don't have a prefix, i.e. there is no "xsp:") and use ${expressions} similar to Expression Language. We are transitioning from a .Net system, so all of my fellow devs are very used to having thorough IntelliSense available in our editors.

So, my question is whether it is possible to make these custom tags available in content assist, and whether it is worth the hassle if there is any. (I'm aware the latter is subjective - I'm a reasonable guy and open to opinions.)

FYI, I'm more concerned with auto-completion of tags, but expressions would be great as well depending on how much work is involved. We are using eclipse for Java EE, Juno (core IDE v4.2.1) with WTP... Sorry I'm not really sure how or what to share as far as versions and components go! Let me know if any additional info would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were the templates actually JSPs, it would just work via a `taglib` directive. Screenshots: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/2.0/newandnoteworthy/jee.php.  You might be looking at making an Eclipse plug-in to provide superior editing of a proprietary template language.

Answer (score 1):

A decidedly non-hassle-free answer would be to create an Eclipse plug-in to support your proprietary template language.  One place to start might be [Veloeclipse](http://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/), a HTML/XML/JSP/Velocity Editor for Eclipse, which claims to have the following features which you may find interesting:

- Smart indentation of velocity directives (on pressing return or when using tabs)
- Code folding
- Code Formatting
- Smart indentation of html tags (on pressing return or when using tabs)
- Syntax highlighting for both html and velocity
- **Autocompletion and Content assist for tags, directives and references** (Ctrl + space in html attribute values or when opening or closing tags)

Sources here: http://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/source/checkout

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion and for highlighting that feature (it's a ways down the list on the project page, I might have missed it if you hadn't pointed it out!) This looks like it might work perfectly. Going to show it to the team and give it a try, and I'll return to set this as the answer, hopefully!

Comment: @David J. Liszewski I use a MAC and when I try to do autocomplete (Ctrl + Space) I get &nbsp; Do I have to configure anything else?